# Mssql How to get the desired XML tag with "OPENXML"?

Tags: sql-server, soap, openxml

I'm using Microsoft Sql 2012 Express

Using "sp_OAGetProperty" from "Soap Service" I get an "nvarchar (max)" value as follows.

```html
--uuid:ec76ddb3-a0ef-4e4d-980d-2dcddd967e44+id=343  Content-ID: 
<http://tempuri.org/0>  Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit  Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="application/soap+xml"    
    <s:Envelope
        xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <s:Body
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <LoginResponse
                xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
                <LoginResult>true</LoginResult>
                <sessionID>eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJqdGkiOiIwZmIxNTVhMi0wOTgwLTQwMGQtODdkOC1kYTQ4MzZiMTk1YzEiLCJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9zaWQiOiI5IiwiaHR0cDovL3NjaGVtYXMueG1sc29hcC5vcmcvd3MvMjAwNS8wNS9pZGVudGl0eS9jbGFpbXMvbmFtZSI6IlVCTDJAVEVTVC5DT00jghjghU</sessionID>
            </LoginResponse>
        </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
--uuid:ec76ddb3-a0ef-4e4d-980d-2dcddd967e44+id=343--
```

I am trying to get LoginResult, sessionID values ​​from this XML with code.

I will use this coding continuation as well. Example I will start another "soapService" and send sessionID.

```html
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @Yanit OUTPUT,
                            @XML
SELECT LoginResult,
       sessionID
FROM OPENXML(@XML, 's:Envelope/s:Body/LoginResponse')
WITH
(
LoginResult [varchar](500) 'LoginResult',
sessionID [varchar](500) 'sessionID'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @Yanit
```

This is the code I last tried, but it returns the error message to me.

Msg 225, Level 16, State 12, Line 193
The parameters supplied for the function "OpenXML" are not valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .value to get to the xml content.

I have modified the XML slightly to suit (as I didn't have time) but this should get you there with a bit of tweaking

```
declare @raw_xml xml = '<Envelope >
  <Body >
            <LoginResponse >
                <LoginResult>true</LoginResult>
                <sessionID>eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJqdGkiOiIwZmIxNTVhMi0wOTgwLTQwMGQtODdkOC1kYTQ4MzZiMTk1YzEiLCJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9zaWQiOiI5IiwiaHR0cDovL3NjaGVtYXMueG1sc29hcC5vcmcvd3MvMjAwNS8wNS9pZGVudGl0eS9jbGFpbXMvbmFtZSI6IlVCTDJAVEVTVC5DT00jghjghU</sessionID>
            </LoginResponse>
        </Body>
    </Envelope>'

    select @raw_xml
    
    
    ,@raw_xml.value('(Envelope/Body/LoginResponse/LoginResult/text())[1]', 'varchar(10)') login_result
    ,@raw_xml.value('(Envelope/Body/LoginResponse/sessionID/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)') login_result
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know that question is old, but if someone has same problem, consider following:

0. The error message told you that parameter is wrong - when invoking
   OpenXML function you need to pass reference for DOM representation
   in memory, which is given as OUTPUT parameter in
   sp_xml_preparedocument procedure (variable *@Yanit* in your case);
1. Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openxml-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
2. Use parameter *flag* with value 2 to tell the function to fetch **elements** (LoginResult, sessionID) within 's:Envelope/s:Body/LoginResponse':

   FROM OPENXML(@XML, 's:Envelope/s:Body/LoginResponse', **2**)